# How to get a node from a complex nested JSON response in Python

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Hi I've a nested JSON response, need to get specific node(obviously, a nested structure). In the below given example, assume it is 'body', if it does not contain any inner nodes then return the same element, ie. 'body' , if the 'body' has 'Message' node in it, then it should return the 'Message' node. How can I handle this scenario in Python.

```
{
  "messageId": "56ba2b85-fb61-4a28-97d3-941237228582",
  "receiptHandle": "AQEB9mKPGdkuDgQkH3tNZ5pMd",
  "body": {
    "Type": "Notification",
    "MessageId": "467a4ce6-4a1e-5cab-8801-1be6b30a621f",
    "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:ttttt:TEST",
    "Subject": "01  Publish for TEST ",
    "Message": "{\\\"Store\\\":\\\"I01\\\",\\\"Loc\\\":\\\"I03\\\",\\\"User\\\":\\\"P37\\\",\\\"Mile\\\":\\\"1500\\\",\\\"Status\\\":true}\"",
    "Timestamp": "2020-04-03T08:41:56.047Z",
    "SignatureVersion": "1",
    "Signature": "Kg",
    "SigningCertURL": "something.com",
    "UnsubscribeURL": "subscribermoke.com"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "ApproximateReceiveCount": "42",
    "SentTimestamp": "1585903316106",
    "SenderId": "AIDAJQR6QDGQ7PATMSYEY",
    "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1585903316106"
  },
  "messageAttributes": {},
  "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
  "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-:jjjjjj:sample-Dev",
  "awsRegion": "us-east"
}
```

**Additional Info:** 
Here is a small change in the JSON body, please find it for your reference.

"Message" : "{\"Store\":\"I01\",\"Loc\":\"I03\",\"User\":\"P37\",\"Mile\":\"1500\",\"Status\":true}"
I want the content inside the "Message" as dict

Comment: First: show us your work and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Third: I have a hunch your "body" element is "double encoded": looks like someone JSON encoded a message, and made that resulting string the value of the "body" element which was then JSON encoded again.  This is -- IMO -- very sloppy design.  This can be accomodated in the decoder... you'll just need to make educated guess when to do the JSON decode additional times.

Comment: I just have this JSON response, that's the beginning of the story. sometimes the 'body' contains no nodes, instead, it would contain the JSON string that I've given in the "Message" node. Sometimes body contain child nodes just like I've shared in the structure. I want to get the JSON string and pass it to an HTTP endpoint.

Comment: this structure is not designed by me. I've to get that content inside the "body" and make it a <dict>

Comment: Sometimes "body" would not contain child nodes, instead it would contain the json string (provided in the "message" key)

Answer (score -1):

You need some form of recursion... but first you need to fix your data object (I think).

This is the outline of what you need:

```
from pprint import pprint
import json

MESSAGE = {
  "messageId": "56ba2b85-fb61-4a28-97d3-941237228582",
  "receiptHandle": "AQEB9mKPGdkuDgQkH3tNZ5pMd",
  "body": {
    "Type": "Notification",
    "MessageId": "467a4ce6-4a1e-5cab-8801-1be6b30a621f",
    "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:ttttt:TEST",
    "Subject": "01  Publish for TEST ",
    "Message": "{\\\"Store\\\":\\\"I01\\\",\\\"Loc\\\":\\\"I03\\\",\\\"User\\\":\\\"P37\\\",\\\"Mile\\\":\\\"1500\\\",\\\"Status\\\":true}\"",
    "Timestamp": "2020-04-03T08:41:56.047Z",
    "SignatureVersion": "1",
    "Signature": "Kg",
    "SigningCertURL": "something.com",
    "UnsubscribeURL": "subscribermoke.com"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "ApproximateReceiveCount": "42",
    "SentTimestamp": "1585903316106",
    "SenderId": "AIDAJQR6QDGQ7PATMSYEY",
    "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1585903316106"
  },
  "messageAttributes": {},
  "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
  "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-:jjjjjj:sample-Dev",
  "awsRegion": "us-east"
}

def find_messages_in_body(body):
    if "Message" in body:
        submsg = body["Message"]
        print(submsg)
        print(type(submsg))
        submsg = json.loads(submsg)
        submsg = find_messages_in_body(submsg)
        return(submsg)
    else:
        return body

pprint(find_messages_in_body(MESSAGE["body"]))
```

But when you run this, you'll find it bombs because the value of the `submsg` is a string, but not a valid JSON string.

So... what, again, is your desired output?  Are you sure you copy-pasted the input data correctly?  Do you have any other input data examples?

Also... is it possible there will be multiple possible "sub messages"?  If so, you'd need to have this return a list, or convert it to a generator (with `yield` instead of `return` statements).  BUT FIRST... check your data object: `MESSAGE["body"]["Message"]` is not valid JSON at this time.